# cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError) Dev Environment Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment, pty

I've been struggling to put together my dev environment while getting this error after I've had a clean bundle install with zero issues as well as checking that my rbenv is set up and my ruby version is set to the correct dev environment requirements. Whenever I try to boot up the rails server or console I am met with the error below.

```rb
/Users/devadmin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require`: cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
```

I have tried installing rubysl-pty to no avail as well as setting up the environment from scratch multiple times still getting this error. I am currently on a Mac using Big Sur I am not really sure where to begin with this issue as pty comes supported with Ruby but I have reinstalled it and rbenv multiple times to still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I also see this kind of errors
You should try add `RAILS_ENV=development` to your command line, I hope it work.

Example

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s
```

Comment: I tried this and still received the same error. I've been having I am not really sure what the issue is.